# Reading multiple values for single field in SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, clrstoredprocedure

Could someone please let me know how to handle this situation?

I have a scenario where I need to read multiple values for a single column by calling an SQL stored procedure just once.

Ex: In the data I have name1, name2, name3, name4 and I need to call an SQL stored procedure once to read all these names and store them in the table.

Comment: can you show what you've tried?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your scenario. Do you have comma separated values in one string and you need to pass it as a parameter to an stored procedure in witch this string would be parsed/split and inserted as multiple rows in a table?

Comment: Yes, with comma separated, but it will have other information as well like Name1, Address1, Name2, Address2... 10, other fields information that occur only once.

Comment: its like XXX, YYYY, UUUU, MMMM, Name1, Address1,                    ...Name10, Address10. In this case I need to store the XXX, YYYY, UUUU, MMMM information inone table and for Name and Address loop through each of details and store by calling the stored procedure only once.

Comment: why can't you split out the records in the code and just pass the fields needed to a stored procedure?

Comment: No, I can't because, I need to read each data set one time and call stored procedure on time, because, I have 1000's of same kind of data sets are in Que for processing. Please let me know if any other ways to handle this scenario. Thanks.